# Mysql foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

When trying to create a table and alter it with the below query:

```
CREATE TABLE `sms_codes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
)

ALTER TABLE `sms_codes`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sms_codes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I got the error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE `sms_codes` ADD CONSTRAINT `sms_codes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_' at line 11

Comment: Add a semi-colon after the end of the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Each statement need to separate by the delimiter `;`. So add the `;` in end of the `CREATE TABLE` in the same way how you added `;` in end of the `ALTER TABLE` statement:

In this line:

```
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
); <-- here
```